# Marquee replacement with css keyfranes animation

Tags: html, css

I want to make a "player like" bar that displays the now playing text as the marquee does. At the moment I have this:

```
<div class="bar">
    <div id="pp" onClick="pl()"><img src="play-256.png"></div>
    <div id="np" class="marquee"><p>Playlist Empty</p></div>
</div>
```

[image: gif with text scrolling]

The css looks something like this:

```
.bar {
    height: 50px;
    width: 800px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: brown;
    margin-top: 20%;
}
.marquee {
    width: 90%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.marquee p {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 50px;
    animation: mrq 15s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes mrq {
    0%  {transform:translateX(100%);}
    100%{transform:translateX(-100%);}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
.bar {
    width: 90%;
}
.marquee {
    width: 75%;
}
.marquee p {
    animation: mrq 5s linear infinite;
}
}
```

The problem apears on responsive:

[image: gif with text scrolling]

As you can see, on the responsive the text gets hidden for whatever reason. What am I doing wrong?

(the onClick="pl()" changes the text insited the "np" div and plays/pauses the song)

P.S. I know I wrote satellites wrong, too lazy to redo the gifs.

Comment: Probably a line break, because you didn't do anything to prevent that at such small widths. `white-space` property might help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to prevent the line breaks since it cuts the text off if the width is too low for the whole text. Since you are using a `paragraph` just add `display:inline` to the style and that would fix the problem:

```
.marquee p {
    animation: mrq 5s linear infinite;
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: the "display: inline;" breakes the keyframe animation

Comment: do you have a plunker or fiddle? @Dddsasul

Comment: sorry, I don't know what thoes are but i think not